# Tell me how to get the necessary time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
   import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from 'react-datepicker';
   import { uk } from 'date-fns/locale/uk';
   import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
   import React, {   useState } from 'react';
   export const Time()=>{
   registerLocale('uk', uk);
   const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
   return (
    <Formik
     dateFormat="H:mm"
     initialValues={{ time: startDate }}
     onSubmit={async values => {
       await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
     >
      <Form>
       <DatePicker
        locale="uk"
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
        showTimeSelect
        showTimeSelectOnly
        timeIntervals={30}
        timeCaption="Time"
        dateFormat="H:mm"
      />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </Form> 
   </Formik>)}
```

Mon Dec 25 2023 13:00:00 GMT+0200
{
"time": "2023-12-25T10:06:04.507Z"
}
I expect to receive the sent time, but I will receive a difference of two hours

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the time zone for the **DatePicker** component. You can use the **timeZone** prop to set the desired time zone for the picker. In your case, it seems like you want to use the 'uk' locale, so you should set the time zone accordingly.

I added **timeZone="Europe/London"** prop to the **DatePicker** component. Adjust the time zone to match the time zone you want for your application.

```
<DatePicker
      locale="uk"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      showTimeSelectOnly
      timeIntervals={30}
      timeCaption="Time"
      dateFormat="H:mm"
      timeZone="Europe/London"
    />
```

Comment: the necessary date is written in startDate, but when it is entered in Formik, it becomes different, I don't understand why